# How to insert data in specific row in sql

Tags: mysql

So here is my problem, I want to add another entry to my database into a specific row.

eg. I have a table "example" then 2 column "name" "age", there are existing data to my table, I have 3 entry

```
   jude,15,
   joy,17,
   john,16
```

respectively but I want to insert another entry

```
jason,18
```

in the row before "joy,17".

Is it possible or impossible?

Comment: You are trying to hard-code. Why do you want to do so?

Comment: It's not possible, but it's also not _meaningful_ since SQL tables are basically unorderee sets of records.

Comment: Yeah it's not posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Francis, the data in a SQL database has no implicit order. So, you can't count on the data coming out in the same order in which you inserted it. The order in which data comes out of a SQL database can only be guaranteed by using an 'ORDER BY' clause on the SQL statement that brings it out of the DB.

Thus, if you want a different sort order than sorting by the keys you've provided, you probably have to add a 'sort' column to your table and use that column in the ORDER BY portion of your SELECT statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so basically it is impossible :D

Comment: I guess impossible is one way to think about it. Another way is to think about insert statements as 'throwing' records into a bag. When you reach your hand into the bag to pull out a record, you don't know if you'll pull them out in the same order in which you put them in. While you might pull them out in that order, it's not guaranteed.